# Count number of specific formula in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA.
I have excel-file with approx 20 sheets. In these sheets there are formula's starting with " =cc.f " (ibm cognos). 
I would like to count (using vba) these formula's in the whole workbook and have the total number of formula's returned to me.

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds doable - loop through each sheet, find formulas using [`SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) and then check if the formula begins with `=cc.f`...

Answer (score 1):

thanks for showing direction: i have now with some workaround first find the formula's with cc.f than replace it by "XYZ" and than count. This can be faster but i do not know how. Further to my code is that the counting does only one sheet and not all sheets.

```
Sub Countccf()

Dim oCell As Range
Dim oSh As Worksheet
Dim iVal As Integer

On Error Resume Next
For Each oSh In Worksheets
For Each oCell In oSh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
If InStr(oCell.Formula, "cc.f") > 0 Then
oCell.Replace what:="*cc.f*", Replacement:="XYZ"

End If
Next
Next

iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:ZZ65012"), "XYZ")
MsgBox iVal

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the worksheet CountIF formulas as a function in VBA

```
Range("Output Cell").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTIF(Range("Your Range"),"*=cc.f*")
```

Off my phone at the moment so can't test if that works proper, but after you fiddle with it a bit it should do the trick. I suggest looking up some CountIF VBA questions here on SO, a lot of people have posted many creative approaches to this one